# how to use Graph Api for deleting an object

Tags: c#-3.0

I m working on c# .net web application.I m using Facebook API for retrieving data from Facebook account.
Now i want to delete wall post or inbox messages through API. i saw that it can be done by graph api,through deleting object.

i try this

```
        string token1 = api.Auth.CreateToken(); 

       string sURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/Post_id?token=" + token + "&method=delete";  

       WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sURL);        

     request.Method = "POST";      

     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

but it gives an error in fourth line "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." ,

Please reply how to solve this

thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Use `access_token` instead of `token`.

Comment: hi 
 Sam, thanks for reply....I already tried this,and yes it deleated the post.But it only deleted those post which is created by our application.

Is there any other way so that we can delete all type of post rather it was created by application or direct create in account.